# How to filter Datasource using mutliselect dropdown

Tags: angular, linq, kendo-multiselect

I am using kendo-multiselect control in my angular application.

```
<kendo-multiselect [data]="airlinesInData" [(ngModel)]="value"  [(value)]="aircodeselect"  [textField]="'Airline'" [valueField]="'Code'" (valueChange)="applyFilters()" [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-multiselect>
```

It is giving me the comma separated value i.e. VS,IA etc.
Following is my linq query

```
 currentDataSource = new List<IDetailRow>(currentDataSource).Where(x => x.firstSegmentAirline == this.aircodeselect).ToArray();
```

How i will filter for each value in a string a return the final result.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this. Instead of using `==` use LINQ `contains` which will compare with all selected codes.

currentDataSource = new List(currentDataSource).Where(x => this.aircodeselect.Contains(x.firstSegmentAirline)).ToArray();